# Compare two lists of lists in Python and find the difference between lists with the same indices

Tags: python, list

For example, if we have

```
ListofLists1 = [[0], [0], [1, 3], [1, 4], []]
```

and

```
ListofLists2 = [[0, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3]]
```

and we define

```
Diff = ListofLists2 - ListofLists1
```

I would like to have the output in the following form

```
Diff = [[2], [1,2,3], [4], [3], [0,1,3]]
```

For the specific kind of work that I am doing, I always expect to find all elements in any list inside ListofLists1 contained inside the corresponding (same index) list in ListofLists2. However, a list inside ListofLists2 may contain elements that are not present inside the corresponding list in ListofLists1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.
Take a good try at this yourself before asking for help.  Post your attempt per the Stack Overflow guidelines, and we'll give it a shot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zip the two lists together, iterate through them as part of a list comprehension and find the set  symmetric difference in each case, setting each resulting set to a list type:

```
ListofLists1 = [[0], [0], [1, 3], [1, 4], []] 
ListofLists2 = [[0, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3]]

[list(set(l1).symmetric_difference(l2)) for l1,l2 in zip(ListofLists1,ListofLists2)]
```

Gives:

```
[[2], [1, 2, 3], [4], [3], [0, 1, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution hit my brain just now. What about

```
Diff = map( lambda x,y: list(set(x) - set(y)), ListofLists2, ListofLists1 )
```

This also returns

```
Diff = [[2], [1,2,3], [4], [3], [0,1,3]]
```

for

```
ListofLists1 = [[0], [0], [1, 3], [1, 4], []] 
ListofLists2 = [[0, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 4], [0, 1, 3]]
```

Any thoughts on how this method would compare with [psychemedia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/454773/psychemedia)'s answer (in terms of speed of implementation for lists which are typically tens of million in length)?